# sqldf - loop through several elements in character vector

Tags: r

I've seen elsewhere on this site that a single variable can be passed to sqldf but I haven't been able to track down a way to loop though all the values in "myplace":

```
myplace <- ("place1", "place2", "place3", ...)

myquery <- sqldf(select things from mydata where place = myplace)

myplace.graph1 <- ggplot2(myquery)
```

My aim is to automate the production of a number of tables and graphs for each "myplace" element - I want to do this as my dataset is updated monthly and I have to report on it. (For this reason, I don't think grouping, as suggested by a similar query on this site, is the way to go although I stand to be corrected).

I am in the process of learning the R ropes in order to replace a bunch of muddled spreadsheets - my data is now in in sqlite but I couldn't see a way of looping through a "dbgetQuery" either.

It could well be that a completely different approach is required - I'm exploring R because the graphs look great, I can document my steps and it's open source - I would appreciate any advice.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

1) A query is just a text string. You can manipulate that text string in all the usual ways before passing it to `sqldf`. See `?paste`, `?paste0`, `?sprintf`, etc.

```
qry <- paste("select things from mydata where place =", myplace[1])
myplace.graph1 <- plot(sqldf(qry))

myplace.graph <- list()
for(i in seq_along(myplace))
{
    qry <- paste("select things from mydata where place =", myplace[i])
    myplace.graph[[i]] <- plot(sqldf(qry))
}
```

2) Or, without a loop:

```
myplace.graph <- lapply(myplace, function(x) {
    qry <- paste("select things from mydata where place =", x)
    plot(sqldf(qry))
}
```

3) Or using `$.fn` from the [gsubfn](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) package (which is automatically loaded by sqldf so is available) as in [Example 5](https://code.google.com/p/sqldf/#Example_5._Insert_Variables) on the [sqldf home page](https://sqldf.googlecode.com):

```
sql <- "select things from mydata where place = '$p' "
lapply(myplace, function(p) plot(fn$sqldf(sql)))
```